# @Html.PagedListPager add a CSS class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have just made a perfect paged list in MVC 5.
On each PagedListPager I want to add a CSS class:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Toetsstart",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: try after this `currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter` adding this:  `, @class="myClassName"`

Comment: You put `@` before `class`, because `class` is also a C# keyword. and you have to let it know that it isn't the C# keyword, but the html class.

Comment: When i do that, the class name is coming in the pagebar.

Comment: @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Toetsstart",
    new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, @class = "help-hulp help-button " }))

Comment: Can you try this; `new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }, new { @class="myClassName" }))`

Comment: if have the answer, there is a file that will give you a css class!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this overload of `PagedListPager` (ref https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList.Mvc/HtmlHelper.cs):

```
public static MvcHtmlString PagedListPager(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html,
                                               IPagedList list,
                                               Func<int, string> generatePageUrl,
                                               PagedListRenderOptions options)
```

Then use the `PagedListRenderOptions` to pass in a class name for whatever element you need (ref: https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList.Mvc/PagedListRenderOptions.cs)

```
public PagedListRenderOptions()
{
    ...
    ClassToApplyToFirstListItemInPager = null;
    ClassToApplyToLastListItemInPager = null;
    ContainerDivClasses = new [] { "pagination-container" };
    UlElementClasses = new[] { "pagination" };
    LiElementClasses = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Adding classes can be done in the `PagedListRenderOptions` like so:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(
    model,
    page => Url.Action("Index",
    new
    {
        page,
        sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort,
        currentFilter = viewBag.CurrentFilter
    }
    ),
    new PagedListRenderOptions()
    {
        LiElementClasses = new List<string> {"myClass", "yourClass"}
    })
```

There are a number of places you can put classes, including:

```
LiElementClasses
ClassToApplyToFirstListItemInPager
ClassToApplyToLastListItemInPager
ContainerDivClasses
UlElementClasses
```

Comment: How do I add the option `OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime` into that options list ?

Comment: @pnizzle You might try `MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 5` after a comma under the `LiElementClasses` in the above example.

Comment: I tried that, won't work unfortunately. `MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay` is defined as a static Get only property

Answer (score 6):

If you would like X.PagedList **Bootstrap 4** compatible just use:

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page }), 
    new PagedListRenderOptions {
        LiElementClasses = new string[] { "page-item" },
        PageClasses = new string[] { "page-link" }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, 
    page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }), 
    new PagedListRenderOptions {                       
    DisplayLinkToIndividualPages = true,
    DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = false,
    MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 10,
    LiElementClasses = new string[] { "page-item" },
        PageClasses = new string[] { "page-link" },
})
```

And also import on top of the page like this:

```
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core.Common;
```

Comment: Could it be that the `,` after `{ "page-link" }` is too much?